# function to add new Objekt in an existing object

Tags: object, methods

i am pretty new to Javascript an had a idea for a small thing to code. The idea was to make an Objekt (kunden) in here we have some clients. In this Objekt i have one existing Client (kunde_1) and a Method (erstellen() ). With the Method i want to add a new client (new Objekt) to the exisiting Objekt (kunden) using a client counter. The counter should count up everytime the function ist called. Here ist my Try, but i have no real idea how to use my counter to create the new client. Here ist the Error that i get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'vorname' on string 'kunde_2'

Is it possible to adjust my code a bit to get it right or am i on a complete wrong path...

```
let count_kunde = 1; // because i already have one client called kunde_1
let kunden = {

erstellen() {
    count_kunde +=1;
    let neuer_kunde = `kunden_${count_kunde}`; // the idea was to create a variable that stores "kunde_2" and through DOT Notation add the values via prompt.
    neuer_kunde.vorname = prompt("Vorname:"),
    neuer_kunde.nachname= prompt("Nachname"),
    neuer_kunde.straße= prompt("Straße"),
    neuer_kunde.hausnummer= prompt("Hausnummer"),
    neuer_kunde.plz= prompt("Plz"),
    neuer_kunde.ort= prompt("Ort")
},

kunde_1: {
    vorname: "Bengt",   
    nachname: "Flecks",
    straße: "Scheffelstraße",
    hausnummer: 33,
    plz: 10367,
    ort: "Berlin"

}

};
```

Here ist the new code after solving the Problem with special thanks to @Deivid Ugarte (with my comments in german):

```
// Anzahl aktueller Kunden zum Start des Programms
let count_kunde = 1; 

// Erstellung des Objektes kunden zum speichern der neu erstellten 
Kunden
let kunden = {

kunde_1: {
    vorname: "Bengt",
    nachame: "Flecks",
    straße: "Scheffelstraße",
    hausnummer: 33,
    plz: 10367,
    ort: "Berlin"
}
};

//Funktion zum erstellen eines neuen Kunden
const kunden_erstellen = function() {

    count_kunde += 1;
    let neuer_kunde = `kunde_${count_kunde}`;
    // Erstellung des Objektes kunden.kunde_n wobei n = count_kunde um 
    im nächsten Schritt die Eigentschaften mit den eingeegebenen Werten 
    hinzuzufügen
    kunden[neuer_kunde] = {}; 
    kunden[neuer_kunde].vorname = prompt("Vorname:"),
    kunden[neuer_kunde].nachname = prompt("Nachname"),
    kunden[neuer_kunde].straße= prompt("Straße"),
    kunden[neuer_kunde].hausnummer= prompt("Hausnummer"),
    kunden[neuer_kunde].plz= prompt("Plz"),
    kunden[neuer_kunde].ort= prompt("Ort")

};

// Funktionsaufruf zum erstellen eines Kunden
kunden_erstellen();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define neuer_kunde as an object `let neuer_kunde = {}` and then assign the name to the object `neuer_kunde.name =` kunden_${count_kunde}.

The error you had was that you are trying to assign a property to the first created string

Comment: Sorry, Dont get it :-) ok. Declaring neuer_kunde as Object makes sens to me. But the name should be kunde_2 (because count_kunde should be at 2 at this moment). defining the object is no problem. but setting the name of that object to "kunden_${count_kunde}doesnt really work. I am so lost ^^

Comment: Oh! I see want you want. You want dynamic names.
So first you need an object to store those. 
Example: 
`let kunden ={} `
then instead of
`neuer_kunde.vorname` you do
`kunden[neuer_kunde].vorname = fooBar`
this will create an object with all the kunden_number as key 
`kunden = { kunden_1: {}, kunden_2:{} ...... kunden_n: {} }`

Comment: Your answers helped me a lot. The main part for me was to create the Objekt  
'''kunden[neuer_kunde] = {};''' in my function - without that it doesnt work - and then set the properties with my promt. Now it does what i want. if i call the function i am creatinig a new kunde_n depending on the number of count_kunde. This is what i ende up with: